# Unknown IllegalArgumentException text cannot be null

Tags: java, android, illegalargumentexception, android-graphview

I'm receiving a weird IAE during one of my activities.

```
08-13 16:24:59.991: E/AndroidRuntime(924): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-13 16:24:59.991: E/AndroidRuntime(924): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: text cannot be null
08-13 16:24:59.991: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at android.graphics.Paint.measureText(Paint.java:1281)
08-13 16:24:59.991: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at com.echo.holographlibrary.BarGraph.onDraw(BarGraph.java:151)
08-13 16:24:59.991: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:10880)
08-13 16:24:59.991: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2899)
08-13 16:24:59.991: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2495)
08-13 16:24:59.991: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2897)
08-13 16:24:59.991: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2495)
08-13 16:24:59.991: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:10883)
08-13 16:24:59.991: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:450)
08-13 16:24:59.991: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at android.widget.ScrollView.draw(ScrollView.java:1524)
08-13 16:24:59.991: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2899)
08-13 16:24:59.991: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2495)
08-13 16:24:59.991: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:10883)
08-13 16:24:59.991: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:450)
08-13 16:24:59.991: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2899)
08-13 16:24:59.991: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2495)
08-13 16:24:59.991: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2897)
08-13 16:24:59.991: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2495)
08-13 16:24:59.991: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:10883)
08-13 16:24:59.991: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:450)
08-13 16:24:59.991: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2106)
08-13 16:24:59.991: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2005)
08-13 16:24:59.991: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1613)
08-13 16:24:59.991: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2418)
08-13 16:24:59.991: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-13 16:24:59.991: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-13 16:24:59.991: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
08-13 16:24:59.991: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-13 16:24:59.991: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-13 16:24:59.991: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
08-13 16:24:59.991: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
08-13 16:24:59.991: E/AndroidRuntime(924):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-13 16:29:41.041: I/Process(924): Sending signal. PID: 924 SIG: 9
```

This worked fine before but now that I've used some dynamic adding to xml, it seemed to have crashed. Below are the calls, and I've been unable to catch this exception.

```
package com.example.exercise;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams;

import com.echo.holographlibrary.Bar;
import com.echo.holographlibrary.BarGraph;

public class GraphDetail extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_graph_detail);
        try{
            boolean done = false;
            int begin = 0;
            int count = 4;
            while(!done)
            {
                if(count>=MainActivity.test.size())
                {
                    done = true;
                    break;
                }
                ArrayList<Bar> points = new ArrayList<Bar>();
                Intent intent1 = getIntent();
                int max = (intent1.getIntExtra("max", 0));
                int[] weight = new int[MainActivity.test.size()];
                for(int i=begin; i<count; i++)
                {
                    weight[i] = MainActivity.test.get(i).getWeight();
                }
                String[] names = new String[MainActivity.test.size()];
                for(int i = begin; i<count; i++)
                {
                    names[i] = MainActivity.test.get(i).getName();
                }

                for(int i = 0; i< weight.length; i++)
                {
                    Bar d = new Bar();
                    if(weight[i]!=max)
                        d.setColor(Color.parseColor("#99CC00"));
                    else
                    {
                        d.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FFBB33"));
                    }

                    d.setName(names[i]);
                    d.setValue(weight[i]);
                    points.add(d);
                }
                Resources r = getResources();
                float px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 130, r.getDisplayMetrics());
                RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);
                int px1 = (int)px;
                BarGraph bar = new BarGraph(this);
                LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
                        px1);
                bar.setBars(points);

                bar.setUnit("0");
                bar.appendUnit(true);
                rl.addView(bar, lp);

                begin+=count;
                count+=3;
                if(count>=MainActivity.test.size())
                {
                    done = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

//          ArrayList<Bar> points = new ArrayList<Bar>();
//          ArrayList<Bar> points1 = new ArrayList<Bar>();
//          ArrayList<Bar> points2 = new ArrayList<Bar>();
//          Intent intent1 = getIntent();
//          int max = (intent1.getIntExtra("max",0));
//          int[] weight = new int[MainActivity.test.size()];
//          for(int i = 0; i<MainActivity.test.size(); i++)
//          {
//              weight[i] = MainActivity.test.get(i).getWeight();
//          }
//          String[] names = new String[MainActivity.test.size()];
//          for(int i = 0; i<MainActivity.test.size(); i++)
//          {
//              names[i] = MainActivity.test.get(i).getName();
//          }
//          for(int i = 0; i< weight.length; i++)
//          {
//              Bar d = new Bar();
//              if(weight[i]!=max)
//                  d.setColor(Color.parseColor("#99CC00"));
//              else
//              {
//                  d.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FFBB33"));
//              }
//                  
//              d.setName(names[i]);
//              d.setValue(weight[i]);
//              if(i<4)
//                  points.add(d);
//              if(i>=4 && i<8)
//                  points1.add(d);
//              if(i>=8)
//                  points2.add(d);
//          }
//          BarGraph g = (BarGraph) findViewById(R.id.graph);
//          g.setBars(points);
//          BarGraph g1 = (BarGraph) findViewById(R.id.graph1);
//          g1.setBars(points1);
//          BarGraph g2 = (BarGraph) findViewById(R.id.graph2);
//          g2.setBars(points2);
//          g.setUnit("0");
//          g.appendUnit(true);
//          g1.setUnit("0");
//          g1.appendUnit(true);
//          g2.setUnit("0");
//          g2.appendUnit(true);
//      


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.graph_detail, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you debug and tell on which line it is crashing?

Comment: I tried catching the error, but it seems to be occurring inside one of the libraries I'm using.

Comment: Oddly enough, I encountered an identical error in a different charting library. The issue turned out to be related to Proguard stripping away too much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String[] names = new String[MainActivity.test.size()];
for(int i = begin; i<count; i++)
{
    names[i] = MainActivity.test.get(i).getName();
}
...
d.setName(names[i]);
...
bar.setBars(points);
```

Have you checked the length of your names array versus count? It's likely that you are generating an array that is larger than the size of count, and because of that you're passing null later to d.setName, which ends up causing an exception later when calling bar.setBars.